# Tkinter Treeview values in loop Python

Tags: python, insert, tkinter, treeview

I have a list of integers and I want to add this ints as values in treeview in Tkinter. Something like that:

Code:

```
  list_of_ints = [1,2,3,4]

  for i in list_of_ints:
    self.tree.insert("" ,0, text="", values=(i,"No. of obj.","Accuracy","Coverage"))
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 No. of obj. Accuracy Coverage
```

Output is columns of treeview. But I really don't know how refer to this values. Moreover I don't know how much values in the array.

Comment: Could you show us more about your code? We need a **simple** working example of your problem, that means that we want to take your code and be able to run it and reproduce your own situation/problem.

Comment: It's very complicated. Main problem is I need transfer values from for loop to the values in treeview. Number of ints in the array must be equal numbers of values in treeview. For every loop add next element of array as value in treeview.

Comment: I understood you want to fill the Treeview with the values from the array, but what exactly is the problem, what is the stack trace Python is giving? Things like this are helpful when trying to help ;)

Comment: Python for every 'i' in loop makes new treeview. I need only one with this values.

Comment: Please, edit your question with your code, so that we can run it and fix it.